# What's the best way to replace NaN values (in a Pandas DataFrame) with values from a separate Pandas Series?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I started with a Pandas DataFrame which has a column with many NaN values.

I split this Pandas DataFrame into two DataFrames: non-NaN and NaN.

I estimated a linear regression model to try to fill in the NaN values (as a function of the other columns).

So I now have a separate Pandas Series that has the estimated values. Its length is the same length as the NaN DataFrame.

I now want to put these estimated values back into the NaN DataFrame, so that I can then ultimately pd.concat() these two DataFrames into one DataFrame that I can then use for my analysis.

I cannot figure out a way to put these values back into the NaN DataFrame into the correct rows. Every time I tried, only some of the NaNs get filled (and probably in the wrong order). It seems to be something to do with the way they're indexed.

```
df_nan["Column"] = y_predicted
```

This is the way I've tried to do it, but it only fills in some of the rows, and incorrectly. Something to do with indices maybe?

Comment: I think you are trying to fill in the missing values in the dataset for your analysis ? If this is the case you don't really need to split the dataframe but use Imputer to fill in the missing values. sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer

Comment: What is the code you've tried so far? The one line you've given is not enough for other users to reproduce the problem, please give all the code from start to finish.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It’s not really a question about code that I’ve written, more about the right approach for solving this sort of problem.

Comment: Check the docs for `pd.DataFrame.update`. Indexes must be the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think a way of doing this could be the following: you keep your raw dataframe and use apply on the column you want to impute.

```
df['imputed_column'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.Column if(pd.notnull(x.Column)) else y_predicted[x.name],axis=1)
```

The following line will get the estimated value if it has a null value (with x.name being the index of the row). Otherwise, it will keep the same value.